# How do B-Trees used in databases sort data based on different fields?

Tags: database, data-structures, sql, data, data-types

I know majority of databases uses B-Trees, and I can see how using a balanced binary tree will give fast sort times, for ordering by ID or whatever else the primary key is; but how are databases able to ORDER_BY different fields like Name or Age, does it just perform an efficient sorting algorithm like merge sort or quick sort on the data or does it store sorted data in B-Trees for all fields (which seems really inefficient for storage). Because ID ordering and Name ordering would be different unless it stores all fields sorted in a B-Tree, it must perform some other sorting algorithm.

TLDR: How are databases able to perform fast sorting on non-primary key fields, if the data stored in B-Tree is based on the primary key.

Comment: It is a good and deep question, but there are two reasons why it had attracted the downvotes and close-votes. (I didn't vote.) This question requires deep and technical answers, and the question asker would have to have already completed at least several university level coursework in database theory and in operating systems to understand. However, the evidence of this is lacking, as seen in the way the question is written. It is possible to improve the writing of this question. Tell us what you have already known; think hard about your own question; explain the crux of your puzzle.

Comment: FWIW SQL Server uses [seven different](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/sql-plan/internals-of-the-seven-sql-server-sorts-part-1) sorts internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in a table can be ordered (this is called a clustered index) but obviously you can only have one sort order. Further indices will not reorder the data, but also they do not contain the data, only the order of rows. If the database does not have an index for the desired ORDER BY clause, it will have to build one on the fly.

Comment: Do you know what sorting algorithm it will use to order the data on the fly?

Comment: No idea, I imagine there a special science behind sorting that's not or not entirely memory based.

Comment: A hybrid of bucket sort, and histogram sort, and N-way merge sort. Basically, it tries to improve over O(N log N) by leveraging the statistical data (histograms) about the column of data that the database maintains for each column. The real pain of (textbook style) merge sort is that the final rounds of merging doesn't have good parallelizability. Databases try to get around that by precomputing where ranges of data should go, so that the merging can send the data very close to the final position (on the sorted list) as early as possible. But ...

Comment: ... sorting on calculated value (i.e. where the database would not have any idea about how the distribution ("histogram") would look like beforehand) would be problematic. There is really no magic algorithm for that; input columns have to be retrieved; formulas for calculated values have to be evaluated; and only then it can start the sorting process. For large datasets, it involves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting , where partially sorted results (or, sorted results from a partition of the data) is dumped back to the disk temporarily.

Comment: @JohnDoe123798: the RDBMS will choose a sorting algorithm that's appropriate for the query. To use Postgres as an example, if the dataset is predicted to be small, Postgres may do an in-memory quicksort, if working on larger data, it may do an on-disk merge sort, if there's a LIMIT clause, it may do a heap sort, if the ORDER BY columns are indexed, it may do an index scan. It's the job of the query planner to pick the "best" sorting algorithm based on its heuristics and table statistics. You can use EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE to find out what sorting method used for a particular query.

Answer (score 2):

In a typical RDBMS the row data lives in a separate area of storage called the heap. The B-tree is just an index pointing into the heap. It is straightforward to construct multiple indexes pointing into the same heap, on an arbitrarily determined key (you can even combine fields or apply functions to them to generate a key). There is a special-case where the row data is stored inside the B-tree, called a clustered index, but even there you can have a second B-tree pointing into the primary index.

In order to access the rows quickly multiple strategies are used. Some columns can be kept inside the index, which is very fast to query, and for the others a page cache can be used to keep the most commonly accessed parts of the heap in RAM. If you have enough RAM to keep the working set entirely in memory the database will perform well even without indexes. For larger working sets an SSD with low latency seeks can help a lot with performance.

The challenge that databases have is to keep all these structures in sync even across crashes. The typical approach is to use a write-ahead log (WAL). Writes are first appended to the log, and a memory cache ensures that reads are serviced from the log instead of the out-of-date B-trees. After the log is flushed to disk the B-trees are also updated. If the database crashes before it has finished updating the B-trees, on next startup it will recover from the WAL and finish the update.

If you want to learn more, you can follow along with the notes from [this slide deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ovHHGT-H-wfGlRqYB1V-1aydSz3O4W9xR7kMQEIJ7CI/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if the B-Tree just stores the primary key sorted, how is it able to sort data from other fields (i.e ORDER_BY) really fast? What kind of sorting algorithm does it use?

Comment: The B-tree is kept in sorted order by its key. This can be the primary key of the table, but any other key can be used as well. The modifications to the B-tree on disk are done in such a way that it is always kept in sorted order. By having multiple B-trees based on different keys, sorting can be done efficiently on any one of those keys, ascending or descending.

Answer (score 1):

Noone here can tell you if *any* database works like this, but I am pretty sure in most cases this is quite simple:

- For any field or combination of fields where an **index** was created beforehand, this index is utilized whenever the ORDER_BY clause contains the related fields. That index could be implemented as a B-tree.
- For any other field (or combination of fields), a sorting algorithm is picked and the sorting is done on-the-fly. Which sorting algorithm is used depends most probably on the specific DBMS and how sophisticated it is implemented, but I can imagine systems which decide on the algorithm depending on some heuristics like the number of records to sort, size of the key fields and if it likely they fit into main memory or not.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it will create an index (for example a B tree) for the primary key automatically and allow the database administrator to create aditional indices for other columns, combinations of columns or expressions over column values. As you point out this trades some space (and insertion speed) for retrival speed. So to get the best performance add enough indices but not more than needed. If no index is present the database will use some sorting algorithm to sort the data on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a database keeps the row data separate from the index.

Rows are stored in pages (see e.g. the details of [how it's done in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)), and for each indexed field (or field combination), there is a B-Tree index which does not contain the actual row data, it only contains a pointer to the page and an index within the page. There's actually nothing special about the primary key on the technical level, it's just another index.

Note that in this design, if you only have operations involving indexed fields (such as WHERE clauses, ORDER BY and joins), you don't even have to look at the actual rows until you have to output the result. The (page, index) tuple uniquely identifies the row, and you can perform all operations using only that, and then in the end you fetch all the row data in one go.